# Updating multiple MongoDB records in Sails.js

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I need to update multiple records in mongodb.

From frontend logic , i got the array of id's as below.

ids: [ [ '530ac94c9ff87b5215a0d6e6', '530ac89a7345edc214618b25' ] ]

I have an array of ids as above , i need to update the folder field for all the records in that array.

I tried passing the id's to mongodb query as below , but still that doesn't work.

```
       Post.native(function(err, collection) {

           collection.update({
                        _id : {
                             "$in" : ids
                              }
                       }, { folder : 'X'}, {
                              multi : true
                       }, function(err, result) {
                        console.log(result);
                       });
                   });
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" a little better. What happens? What do you expect. Show your documents (just a few) that you want to update and what you expect in your results. Edit your question, and don't put this in comments please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two possible problems.

1) your ids array is not an array of ids, it's an array which has a single element which is itself an array, which has two elements.   An array of ids would be `[ 'idvalue1', 'idvalue2']

2) your id values inside of arrays are strings - is that how you are storing your "_id" values?   If they are ObjectId() type then they are not a string but a type ObjectId("stringhere") which is not the same type and won't be equal to "stringhere".

Comment: Or possibly there is no way of knowing yet, as there is no data, could possibly need use of $set, could be the wrong invocation in sails, could be written client side .... I'd prefer to **know** rather than speculate. The question needs more info. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks for advice, Neil. I think the fact that ids is not an array of ids is visible in the question. True once the query predicate matches, it's possible the update action will not be what OP desires - *that* part does need more data, which is why I didn't speculate about it.

Comment: ya , as you said the id values inside the arrays are strings ,...how can i transform that to objectids and pass that to the query

Comment: new ObjectId("24charhexstringhere") will create one of those objects.

Comment: After changing my frontend logic , now the input obtained is as below.   [ '530ac7fe5ccd73e113ef6118',
     '530ac3b49af8a09813fe11fd',
     '530abb29e932f8e5104b8ccc' ] ... I passed this input to the query as in my question still the records are not updated .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick replies. My issue sorted out. Thanks alot again :)

Comment: @Mahahari if an answer solves your problem, please accept it (checkmark next to the answer).  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use the `native` method in this case.  Just do:

```
Post.update({id : ids}, {folder : 'X'}).exec(console.log);
```

Waterline automatically does an "in" query when you set a criteria property to an array, and Sails-Mongo automatically translates "id" to "_id" and handles ObjectId translation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Those strings look like the string representation of mongod ObjectIds, so probably what you want to do is turn them into ObjectIds before querying. Assuming you've corrected your problem with the extra level of nesting in the array, that is:

```
ids = ['530ac94c9ff87b5215a0d6e6', '530ac89a7345edc214618b25']
```

Then you want to do something like this:

```
oids = []
for (var i in ids)
    oids.push(ObjectId(ids[i]))

db.c.find({_id: {$in: oids}})
```

Does that fix your problem?